# How can I filter data from a table with a Foreign Key?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
#- coding: utf-8 -#

STATUSES = (
    (u'R', u'Solicitada'),           # Request
    (u'V', u'Válida'),               # Deposit
    (u'P', u'Imprimiendo'),          # Printing
    (u'S', u'Por Entregar'),         # Stock
    (u'D', u'Entregada'),            # Delivered
    (u'F', u'Olvidadas')             # Forget
)

class Order(models.Model):
    requester = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class OrderStatus(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name="statuses")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=STATUSES)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I need to filter the Orders by status and by date. I've tried the following:

```
orders_sold = Order.objects.all()
orders_sold = orders_sold.filter(statuses__status='V')
```

But it returns whatever it wants, and with the date, I've tried:

```
orders_sold = orders_sold.filter(statuses__date__range=[from_date,to_date])
```

But it says that "date" doesn't exists.

How can I achieve what I'm looking to do?

UPDATE

The error that "date" gives is this:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'date' into field. Choices are: added, additionalinfoorder, email, id, orderitems, password, payment, payment_date, payments, phone, print_orders, requester, statuses, taker, viewed
```

Comment: @Roger_Gonzalez I think your first query works, are you sure there's at least one Order which status was never 'V'?

Comment: Yes, I have several status (At least 20 on every status). When I select only the 'V', It returns 'R', 'P' or whatever. The only one that works is the 'F'. @avenet

Comment: Can you add the '"date" doesn't exist' exception traceback to the question?

Comment: See post edit @avenet

Comment: @Roger_Gonzalez I don't understand what you mean when you say it returns 'R', 'P'..etc, as the query should return Orders, not status. I made a simple test with your code, created an order with the 'V' status and another one with the 'P' status and it all works fine.

Comment: @Roger_Gonzalez Can you make sure to run python manage.py migrate? The query you made should work. Also make sure you are working with Order items, not with OrderStatus items and that your OrderStatus model contains the date attribute.

Answer (score 0):

See this [blog post](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/01/11/django-patterns-part-2-efficient-reverse-lookups/); querying on reverse lookups is not exactly a supported feature of Django. You'll have to take a different approach. Here's an idea -

```
order_with_status_v = OrderStatus.objects.filter(status='V',date__range=[from_date,to_date]).values('order')
```

Now, a caveat of this is that `.values()` gathers the values from the SQL relation and stores it in a dictionary; the ID of the foreign key is stored, but other information is lost. So, whatever information you'd want to access must be listed in the args for `values`:

```
.values('order', 'order__requester')
```

In order to do this in a scant 2 db hits, try the following:

```
# list of the PK of all orders referenced by any OrderStatus with status "V"
order_statuses_v = OrderStatus.objects.filter(status='V',date__range=[from_date,to_date]).values_list('order__pk',flat=True)
# All orders referenced by OrderStatus with status "V"
orders_sold = Order.objects.filter(pk__in=order_statuses_v)
```

Comment: I think the article you are linking to does not say explicity that reverse lookups are not supported by Django. As I understand it says it's not always the best way to query as it makes a lot of queries to the DB.

Comment: Well, not supported as part of the ORM querying mechanisms (every time you call `some_object.related_objects.all()`, you will hit the db). In your case, it is probably best to start your querying at the `OrderStatus` level. I will add another option to the response above.

Comment: Looks like we have different ideas of 'supported', but diversity of opinions is great :), I agree with the performance part...

Answer (score 0):

First, your `date` field it seems to be empty. You could make it save date when first created an `OrderStatus` object:

```
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now that you have a `date` you can filter by `status` *and* by `date`:

```
orders_sold = Order.objects.filter(statuses__status='V', statuses__date__range=(from_date,to_date))
```

Comment: I do have 'date' populated, I'm getting it from a form. It just says that "statuses__date" doesn't exists.

Comment: @RogerGonzalez are you sure the name of your `DateTime` field is `date`?